# Python curse getmouse function?

Tags: python, mouseevent, curses

I'm trying to find a way to get mouse click event in curse module in Python.

I read the document on http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html and it suggested to do

```
c == curses.getch()
if(c == curses.KEY_MOUSE):
    curses.getmouse()
    ...
```

However, this "if statement" seems to never get triggered... and if I tried to move the getmouse() function outside of "if statement" to force it to return the mouse information, it return

```
    (devid,x,y,z,bstate) = curses.getmouse()
_curses.error: getmouse() returned ERR
```

Any other thought?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you enabled mouse-event reporting with the [mousemask](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.mousemask) function, and checked its return value to make sure it confirms that it can actually report some mouse-events?  Depending on the terminal (or emulator program for one, these days;-), mouse event reporting may or may not be possible, in whole or in part; and in any case, it's disabled by default in curses (not just on Python, that's a curses general idea;-) unless and until you explicitly enable it with the `mousemask` call.

Comment: After I enable the mousemask function, it works as I expected. Thanks for your prompt reply.